# iOS reroute sounds to earpiece

Tags: ios

I have an app for iOS in Xcode. I have a music player that plays songs from the iPod library in the app.  What I want to do is reroute the iPod music to the earpiece. Basically I first want to know if this is possible. Also I want to know how to do it, but I know that this website is not a code writing website so if I can just get some tips on how to do it that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: One, what framework or class are you using. Second, yes it is possible, MPMusicPlayer does it by default I believe.

Comment: i am using the media player framework

Comment: Well, I think we are agreed that you're going to try to do this by configuring your AVAudioSession, where when you call `setCategory:withOptions:error:` you're going to use AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord and _not_ supply `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker` as an option. Try this and see if it does what you're after.